# preg_match_all Specific REGEX

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Could some one help me to formulate this REGEX because i am not familiar with preg_match_all filters, I want REGEX for :

1. sentence containing "petition" and delimited by . or a line break
2. Postal code have the format XXXXX (number) (with eventual space between the numbers ex : X XX XX or X XXXX )

```
$phone_regex =  '~(?:\+?169|0)(?:\s*\d{3}){2}\s*\d{4}~';
$phone_res = preg_match_all($phone_regex, $content, $phone_matches);
```

REGEX 1

input : 
1=> Plus de 5500 personnes ont déjà signé la pétition en ligne. Dans la droite ligne de ce mouvement, une manifestation est organisée jeudi devant la mairie de Metz.

2=> Dans un communiqué pétition 
La décision de la Ville de Metz de confier les cinémas

output: 
1=> Plus de 5500 personnes ont déjà signé la pétition en ligne. 
2=> Dans un communiqué pétition

REGEX 2

input : 
1=> 50040 
2=> 50 040 
3=> AA123

output : 
1=> 50040 
2=> 50 040

Comment: It would help if you provide an example string and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([^\.]*pétition[^\.^\n]*\.?)`

And for your zip code : `(\d\s?\d\s?\d\s?\d\s?\d)`

Test this regex here with some sample texts before using it in your code : https://www.regex101.com/